# VNImageRequestHandler and AVCaptureVideoDataOutput videoSettings with kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange

Tags: ios, machine-learning, image-processing, coreml, avcaptureoutput

With `VNImageRequestHandler` we ned to pass `CVImageBuffer`.

Which is basically the output of `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` with a specific videoSetting.

```
    override func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {N
.........
       let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: exifOrientation, options: [:])
......
}
```

Question 1:
Does it have to be `kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange` or it can be `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`?

```
        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]
```

Question 2: In case it allows 32BGRA , then when to use `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` and how does the `VNImageRequestHandler` differentiate between YCBCR and 32BGRA for best and efficient image identification ?